# Fastest way find the edit Distance of a word, given a list of Million words

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary

I have a file with more than a million words, one word in each line. I am trying to write code where if I were given a word I need to find out if that word is present in the file. The thing here is, each word has to be checked for `26^(word.length()-1)` times. Hence, going through every word in the file is not a good solution. I tried finding algorithms online but not have found any appreciable answer yet.

**EDIT**
I have thought about both a `HashMap` and `Trie`. The actual problem here is say I have the word `abc`. Now, my task is to add, remove, or substitute exactly one letter in word `abc` to create word X and then check if X is in the file. Hence am confused as to which solution might be a better approach.

Comment: Are you performing the search in a specific filesystem/OS or many?

Comment: Pardon me for saying it, but it would be much much smarter to stick all your words in a database (relational, key / value, memcache) and look up that way. This is what databases are for

Comment: @LeonardoCooper: Its just one file, a text file to be precise.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question. It is misleading if you are actually looking to find edit distance between dictionary words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can build a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from the words in your file. This will use much less memory than a Hashset and allow you to check the existance of a word in O(number of characters in word). If memory is no concern, of course a Hashset will do (since that is built in its also much less effort).

Comment: @noMAD: Are you trying to calculate edit distance between dictionary words?

Comment: This solution using a trie should also be a good approach for finding approximate matches to a given query.  If you are checking the trie with a recursive function you can use an argument which indicates how many edits you are allowed.  Everytime you go down a non-matching part of the trie you decrement this number.  This should be still be a very efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Store the words in a HashSet in memory, and you'll have O(1) lookups.

Comment: So what? `String s = "abc"; String x = substituteOneLetter(s); return hashSet.contains(x);`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Agreed -- I don't see how the edit changes the suitability of a hash table. I still think it's the best solution! Not sure why the trie is getting so much love :). Thus, +1 for you since people like your HashSet more than my HashTable. Fair enough -- it's probably slightly better suited!

Comment: implementing a good hashcode for, possibly million different strings is hard; and so there is bound to be collisions and O(1) is not guaranteed. So a trie or even better a compressed trie (suffix tree) will give you a O(size of search string).

Comment: Fortunately, the String class already has a good hashCode implementation, and you don't have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your word is "cad" and you are looking to find all words within an edit distance of 1.

In this case, you could do the following.

1) Store the dictionary words in a HashMap. 
2) Generate all combinations of words with an edit distance of 1 to "cad". 
3) For each of these words, test if that word is present in the HashMap.

You search should match words like "dad", "cat", "car", "lad", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a hash table as you read in the file with words in it. You should be able to check if a word is present in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is the way to go. Just store all the words in a HashMap and then look up the map to see if your word exists. Of course, this is useful only if you want multiple look ups.

A more practical solution is to write the HashMap to disk and load it into memory the next time you run your application.

Answer (score 0):

The tabla hast is the more faster way

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String s; (s = in.readLine()) != null;) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). A very fast and space efficient data structure used to check if an element is a member of a set. The cons is that it's a probalistic data structure which means that false positives is possible.

It works by having an array of m bits. When adding a word to the filter, the word is feeded to k different hash functions setting the bits to 1 at the positions calculated by those hashes. When quering the filter, feed the word to the same hashes and check if the bits are set at those positions. If any of those bits are 0, it's sure that the word doesn't exist in the set, if all are 1 a lookup is needed since those bits might have been set when hashing other words to the same positions.